# cycle detection in a directed & disconnected graph

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to find out if a graph contains cycle or not. I have applied dfs. The problem is that my code is classifying any graph as a cyclic one.

Here is my code:

```
public class Graph {
    public static int nodeno;
    public static int edgeno;
    public static int graph[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        nodeno = in.nextInt();
        edgeno = in.nextInt();
        graph = new int[nodeno][nodeno];
        for (int i = 0; i < edgeno; i++) {
            int from = in.nextInt();
            int to = in.nextInt();
            graph[from][to] = 1;
        }
        if (isCyclic())
            System.out.println("Contain cycle");
        else
            System.out.println("No Cycle");

    }

    private static boolean isCyclic() {
        boolean[] visit = new boolean[nodeno];
        boolean[] recStack = new boolean[nodeno];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeno; i++) {
            if (isCyclicUtil(i, visit, recStack))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isCyclicUtil(int s, boolean[] visit, boolean[] recStack) {
        if (visit[s] == false) {
            visit[s] = true;
            recStack[s] = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeno; i++) {
                if (graph[s][i] == 1) {
                    if (!visit[i] && isCyclicUtil(i, visit, recStack))
                        return true;
                    else if (recStack[i])
                        return true;
                }
            }

        }
        recStack[s] = false;
        return false;

    }
}
```

My sample input is

```
4
5
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

Here the output should be `No cycle`but it is showing `contain cycle`. Cant find my fault. Can any ine help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample input doesn't match the reader format. The reader expects a list of edges rather than an adjacency matrix. The supplied graph is really cyclic according to the format you use: the edges are 0->1, 1->0 ..

Probably you meant:

```
4
5
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 3
2 3
```